Swap function in queue and stack: Does it copy each element or swap the addresses? C++
I have been studying on queues and stacks and as an exercise I'm trying to implement them by using the other one (stack with queue and queue with stack). It is possible to do it by using 1 queue or 1 stack but I'm doing it with 2 at the moment. When creating the push() function, as there are 2 queue/stack, after each usage one of the queue/stack is filled and the other is not. (ex: in first push() q1 is empty q2 is filled in next push() q1 is filled q2 is empty) At the end of push() function, I need to swap them so I can always use the same queue/stack for other operations.
What I'm wondering is that if I use std::swap() function, does it copy each element to swap the queue/stack or does it simply swap the addresses.
For now, I simply used a p1 and p2 pointers and swap their values but doing so I have to keep using the said pointers in the whole code as shown below. I'm asking this question because if the std::swap() function is changing the addresses, I can simply use that and don't bother with pointers.
private:
    queue<int> q1, q2;
    queue<int>* p1 = &q1;
    queue<int>* p2 = &q2;
public:
    MyStack() {
        //constructor
    }
    
    void push(int x) {
        (*p2).push(x);
        while(!(*p1).empty())
        {
            (*p2).push((*p1).front());
            (*p1).pop();
        }

        //swap
        queue<int>* temp = p1;
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = temp;

    }

This is a small exercise so having pointers everywhere is just a minor inconvenience but in a bigger project I can save time by using std::swap() instead of using so many pointers or implementing my own swap function if it swaps the addresses instead of swapping elements themselves.

std::queue and std::stack are both container adaptors. Whether swapping values or addresses makes better sense is a decision made in the container they adapt.

Assuming you mean std::stack: the default container for std::stack is std::deque. That means that std::swap(stack1, stack2) calls deque1.swap(deque2). You can find the answer here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/swap "Exchanges the contents of the container with those of other. Does not invoke any move, copy, or swap operations on individual elements."

Side note: The pointers everywhere approach will force you to observe the Rule of Three or Five rather than passively observing the Rule of Zero. It would suck to have a copy constructor/assignment operator that left the copy pointing to the queue instances in the original rather than its own copies of the queues.

As a side note, while I certainly would not use the pointers here at all, you can write things like (*p).push() as p->push() -- which, in my opinion, makes for lighter reading.
